# Problema ao armazenar objeto java em arquivo

Tags: java

Quando eu tento armazenar um objeto em um arquivo binário, o arquivo com a extensão `.bin` é criado. Porém, quando vou tentar acessá-lo por outra classe, ele nem ao menos tenta abrir o arquivo `.bin` que eu gravei o meu objeto. Como resolver o problema?

**Classe Principal**

```
package ordenacao;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        lista l = new lista();
        lista aux = new lista();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x,i;

        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            System.out.println("Digite um valor para empilhar:");
            x = input.nextInt();
            l.InsereInicio(x);
        }
        System.out.println("Dados Inseridos:");
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            x = l.removeInicio();
            aux.InsereFinal(x);
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        l = aux;
        try{
            OutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("lista.bin");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            os.writeObject(l);
            os.close();
            fileStream.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Erro 1");
        }
    }
}
```

**Objeto que estou Querendo armazenar**

```
package ordenacao;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class lista implements Serializable{
    elemento primeiro;
    elemento ultimo;

    public void InsereInicio(int valor){
        elemento novoprimeiro = new elemento();
        novoprimeiro.dado = valor;
        novoprimeiro.proximo = primeiro;
        primeiro = novoprimeiro;
        if(ultimo==null){
            ultimo = novoprimeiro;
        }
    }

    public void InsereFinal(int valor){
        elemento novoultimo = new elemento();
        novoultimo.dado = valor;
        novoultimo.proximo = null;
        if(primeiro == null){
            primeiro = novoultimo;
        }else{
            ultimo.proximo = novoultimo;
        }
        ultimo = novoultimo;
    }

    int estaVazio(){
        if(primeiro==null){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int removeInicio(){
        if(estaVazio()==1){
            System.out.println("Esta vazio");
            return -1;
        }
        int k = primeiro.dado;
        primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
        if(primeiro==null){
            ultimo = null;
        }
        return k;
    }

    int removeFinal(){
        if(estaVazio()==1){
            return -1;
        }
        int k = ultimo.dado;
        elemento fim = primeiro;
        elemento penultimo = null;
        while(fim.proximo!=null){
            penultimo = fim;
            fim = fim.proximo;
        }
        if(penultimo!=null){
            penultimo.proximo = null;
            ultimo = penultimo;
        }else{
            primeiro = null;
            ultimo = null;
        }
        return k;
    }

    int remover(int pos){
        if((pos<0)||(estaVazio()==1)){
            return -1;
        }
        elemento anterior = new elemento();
        elemento atual = primeiro;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<pos-1;i++){
            anterior = atual;
            atual = atual.proximo;
        }
        anterior.proximo = atual.proximo;
        atual = null;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Leitor que deveria ler os dados**

```
package pacotejava;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class PrincipalPacotenovo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            int i;
            lista noval;
        try{
            InputStream conectar = new FileInputStream("lista.bin");
            ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(conectar);
            Object obj = os.readObject();
            noval = (lista)obj;
            for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                System.out.println(noval.removeInicio());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Erro 1");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Erro 2");
        }       
    }
}
```

-------Update-------

Consegui resolver um dos problemas quando joguei throws IOException o compilador acabou por me mostrar as linhas que estavam causando erro(eu não havia fechado o leitor e eu havia me esquecido de implementar em uma das classes do meu pacote o Serializable,e assim consegui compilar o escritor sem problemas),em relação ao leitor eu não obtive a mesma sorte,o erro que apareceu foi o seguinte:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ordenacao.lista cannot be cast to pacotejava.lista
    at pacotejava.PrincipalPacotenovo.main(PrincipalPacotenovo.java:14)
C:\Users\Renan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

Comment: O que você está tentando armazenar num arquivo? Qual o tipo? Tente detalhar melhor o que está tentando fazer, não ficou muito claro.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Qual o erro?

Comment: Como assim "nem mesmo tenta"?

Comment: estou querendo jogar minha lista que eu criei(um objeto) num arquivo,e depois acessar seus dados através de uma outra classe,de outro pacote,o problema é que este programa que eu implementei,não está conseguindo ler esses dados(mesmo o meu programa compilando normalmente),e para testar,tentei jogar um print nas Exceções pegos pelo catch pra ver se ele estava realmente estava dando erro,e ao executar ele estava imprimindo oque eu coloquei(ou seja ele estava dando erro de IO)(OBS.:desculpe se eu nao fui muito claro,tive que sair as pressas e acabei digitando muito rapido)

Answer (score 0):

obrigado por tentarem me ajudar,eu percebi o erro depois um tempinho pensando,a minha ideia era tentar gravar no arquivo meu objeto,a ideia de gravar no arquivo era que ele pudesse converter os dados do objeto em uma cadeia de bits serializada e depois ao ler ele retornasse todos os dados armazenados nesse objeto que foi escrito no arquivo,o problema é que o meu objeto é composto por "ponteiros",e quando eu gravei o objeto lista,ele gravou não apenas os dados como também os "ponteiros" dos outros objetos que estavam na lista,e o problema estava ai,o "ponteiro" de Java é referênciado pelo pacote em que o objeto(arquivo java) se encontra,e eu estava tentando referênciar por um pacote diferente,e ao tentar fazer isso ele estava dando erro pois não conseguia pegar a referência,não pensei que a referência do "ponteiro" dependeria do pacote também.